# Get Request to an API url

Tags: php, api, get, synonym

I have signed up to a synonym API.. see [the details on this page](http://words.bighugelabs.com/api.php)

I am having trouble implementing this in my php code.

If I copy and paste the link into the web browser, I can see the results no problem.

Instead of typing the word in manually, I wish to have a variable in the link with the relevant word i.e. `$variable_with_word_stored` as shown below.

```
    http://words.bighugelabs.com/api/2/xxxxxxxx/$variable_with_word_stored/php 

    //format could be php (I would unserialize)..or json..I could decode it?
```

Any ideas guys? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you mean you want the result from calling that webpage and store it in a variable. What you should be looking to do is sending a http get request to that page within the code.

Check out using curl with php, you can send a http request to your requested url, capture the result back and parse it through `json_decode`

http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php

Answer (score 0):

try it like this, maybe that you dont need curl:

```
$key = "xxxxxxxx";
$word = "love";

echo file_get_contents("http://words.bighugelabs.com/api/2/$key/$word/php");
```